# How to open source code of an app and run in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have the source code of an android app. I want to open it in android studio and run it.
It has two folders :

[image]

In resources folder, the following are the folders:

[image]

In sources folder, the following are the folders:

[image]

I am not sure how do I open this android app and run it in android studio.
I am a new to Android app development and downloaded an app's source code which was available in internet and I am trying to open it in android studio. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: have you decompile android project?

Comment: Yes, Abdur Rehman, I have decompiled android app

Answer (score 0):

Dont think there is an android project inside the file. The directory is usually like this : app/src/main/java/com/example/project_name

Answer (score 0):

To run decompile code of android project, you have to create new project with same package id, than put one by one directory or even one by one line of code and their respective dependency.
There are very less chances, run decompiled code fully because whole code not decompiled accurately. You have to get your required code and understand logic of it.